# Character detection from binary image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, feature-detection, feature-extraction

Hello I'm trying to detect characters on this specific image.

Original Image:

[image]

After some preprocessing I've finally got this image
[image]

Currently I could detect single characters by using SURF feature detection and matching algorithm.

[image]

Also with template matching I could detect single characters.

[image]

But with this algorithms I cannot really classify my matches to detect which character is what. 
After some research and test I decided to use hog descriptors to extract and then train those descriptors with svm to classify.

When I crop those chars for surf and template matching I manually cropped those chars in photshop so sizes are not equal to each other but Hog algorithm uses a specific width * height. so I have to have every characters with same size.

So my question is since I am going to use those method only for the **original image** can I manually crop and resize every char for HOG ? or do I have to first detect each character extract them and then prepare those extracted characters for Hog? If the second one what kind of methods would you suggest me to use?

Comment: Why not using OCR? If you use HoG you probably want to TRAIN with same scale for each char but DETECT with a single rescale for each BLOCK / GROUP of chars to not detect some noise as "i" or sth.

Comment: you mean train each char on tesseract and match them ? @Micka

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about signal/image processing. Use dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I guess you can use tesseract directly without training but I never used it. How/why/where do you want to use HoG?

Comment: hello I am writing an article and going to share results of those methods in my article thats why I try different methods @Micka